# Select rows where values of one column are equal to each other in powerpivot

Tags: sql, powerpivot

I want select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from a big table"Data" where column"f" values are equal to each other and column"a" value is biggest [and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtoZ5.jpg) column"f" values are not equal to each other.

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `f` values equal to each other and then not equal to each other is confusing.

Comment: if RDBMS supports window functions... perhaps.... `SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.A, A.b, A.C, A.D, A.E, A.F, A.G, A.H, A.I, Row_Number() over partition by (b,c ORDER by A Desc) RN
FROM Data A) Z
WHERE RN in (1,2)` assuming b,c are key values for each group. and you always want the two highest "A" values in each group.

Comment: No dont support

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY clause.

GROUP BY aggregates records based on column value equality.

For example:

```
SELECT f, max(a) as a
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY f;
```

You can use this as a subquery to select records from your table with the result's f and max(a) values.